# Remove Random Items from a list in Python with conditions

Tags: python, list, random

I've got this situation:

A range of days (let's say work shifts), and a different number of humans that cannot cover work shifts on specifics days. Each day of the range has to be covered by two workers.

So, the newbie solution I found is that display in lists one below another the days free for each worker, with a `0` mark when they cannot work.

```
period_of_time = range(1,10)

human_1 = [1, 3, 4, 8, "Human 1"]
human_2 = [5, 6, "Human 2"]
human_3 = [8, 9, "Human 3"]
human_4 = [2, 4, 6, "Human 4"]

humans = [human_1, human_2, human_3, human_4]

def looping_function(in_humans):
    new = []
    for d in period_of_time:
        if d not in in_humans:
            new.append(d)
        else:
            new.append(0)
    print(str(new) + " " + human_id + "\n")

for a in humans:
    in_humans = a
    human_id = a[-1]
    looping_function(in_humans)
```

It's works fine.

```
[0, 2, 0, 0, 5, 6, 7, 0, 9] Human 1

[1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 0, 7, 8, 9] Human 2

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 0, 0] Human 3

[1, 0, 3, 0, 5, 0, 7, 8, 9] Human 4
```

And it's useful for now. Considering that I working on it just for learning purposes. Now I want to eliminate random items from the lists, in order to have only two humans for each day of the range. I'm stuck here.

Comment: whats the desired output?

Comment: Hi, @SufiyanGhori. I'd like the same output, but for the first index (the day 1), only two humans on it. Not three, like the actual output. And the same for all the days in the range.

Comment: This sounds like a discrete optimization problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Soulution with usage of your code, you have to just loop through schedule and add ids

```
period_of_time = range(1,10)

human_1 = [1, 3, 4, 8, "Human 1"]
human_2 = [5, 6, "Human 2"]
human_3 = [8, 9, "Human 3"]
human_4 = [2, 4, 6, "Human 4"]

humans = [human_1, human_2, human_3, human_4]

def looping_function(in_humans):
    new = []
    for d in period_of_time:
        if d not in in_humans:
            new.append(d)
        else:
            new.append(0)
    print(str(new) + " " + human_id + "\n")
    return new

schedule = []
for a in humans:

    in_humans = a
    human_id = a[-1]
    schedule.append(looping_function(in_humans))

for x in range(9):
    current_day_workers = 0
    for human in schedule:
        if human[x] != 0: current_day_workers +=1
        if current_day_workers >2: human[x] = 0

print(schedule)
```

Comment: I'll include a random.shuffle on the schedule before the counting, so the shifts will be assigned randomly. Thanks!